# ffmpeg installation on Linux REHEL/CentOs 6.X

Tags: centos, ffmpeg

I had a static installation of `ffmpeg` but was running into trouble with config files not found so I have since just deleted it. Then I tried re-installing a more current static version just to see if it differs from first one I installed a week ago and it does.

The first one had the `ffmpeg` script which I ended up placing in `/usr/bin` and a `ffmpeg-static` folder with `cache` in root. The latest static I just installed has no `static` folder and just two scripts, the `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe`.

I have a few questions:

- Is it best to place these scripts in `usr/bin`, does it matter? Does `yum` update static versions?
- Is it much better practice to compile `ffmpeg` than use static versions?
- Has anyone tried this type of ffmpeg installation as stated in [the following link](http://linuxmaterials.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/installation-ffmpeg-on-linux-rhelcentos.html)?

Comment: actually unfort the directions in first answer didn't work so will open new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q#1: Is it best to place these scripts in usr/bin, does it matter? Does yum update static versions?

No if you download and install the static versions that the FFmpeg project provides on their website will not be managed by `yum` if you opt to install them into `/usr/bin`. I would probably not opt to install these to `/usr/bin`. I'd rather install them into a user's `$HOME/bin` directory instead, to keep them separate from packaged versions which may reside in `/usr/bin`.

> Q#2: Is it much better practice to compile ffmpeg than use static versions?

I've been using the static builds of late on CentOS and Fedora, they simply work and are easy to install and move around. They include all the FFmpeg features and are the easiest by far.

Compiling though easy enough, can present you with issues, and there isn't really that much upside, if you cannot find a pre-packaged version from a YUM repository.

> Q#3: Has anyone tried this type of ffmpeg installation as stated in the following link?

Yes these types of installations are the preferred way to install packages from YUM repositories, when wanting to install software system-wide on a box.

Comment: Thank you for being so specifically helpful.I will give to the first answer though because it is what I will use.

Comment: Didn't work so have changed selection.

Answer (score 1):

Install ATRPMS Repository

```
# rpm --import http://packages.atrpms.net/RPM-GPG-KEY.atrpms

# rpm -ivh http://dl.atrpms.net/all/atrpms-repo-6-7.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Install FFMpeg from ATRPMS Repository

```
# yum -y --enablerepo=atrpms install ffmpeg
```

Verify the version of you have installed

```
# ffmpeg -version
```

To see the Supported format

```
# ffmpeg -formats
```

Convert your Videos, Convert from MP4 to H264 using

```
# ffmpeg -i tamil_gana_720p.avi -vcodec libx264 tamil_gana_720p-H264.avi
```

yes Every Program will be there in /usr/bin for execution

Comment: thanks, is this for 32 bit? and could you pls answer the questions i asked specifically?

Comment: Repository for both 32 and 64 bit

Comment: the executable file will be under usr/bin

Comment: In Default Centos we Won't get ffmpeg, so what we need to add a repository to get install ffmpeg

Comment: Sorry it didn't work.